# Inno Setup: how to use {app} in InitializeWizard Procedure

Tags: inno-setup

How can I gain access to the `{app}` variable in the `InitializeWizard` procedure ?

When I use `ExpandConstant('{app}');` I get the next error message:

> An attempt to expand the {app} constant was made before it was initialized

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer :)

Prototype:

```pascal
function WizardDirValue: String;
```

Description:

> Returns the current contents of the edit control on the Select Destination Location page of the wizard.
>
> Unlike `ExpandConstant('{app}')`, this function will not fail if called after the wizard is shown but prior to the user selecting a directory. Rather, it will return the default directory name.