# innosetup error to expand constant before inizialize

Tags: inno-setup

when i run my innosetup code i return this error : An attempt was made to expand the "app" constant before it was initialized.
I don't understand where to put my  `NextButtonClick` funtion to solve it.
Thanks to all .

This is my code:

```
[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{D174BFCA-6A75-445D-996B-41DD6992B73B}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableDirPage=auto
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputDir=C:\Users\aartoni\Documents\innosetup\progetti\MRV\Output
OutputBaseFilename=MRV_Setup
WizardSmallImageFile=C:\Users\aartoni\Documents\innosetup\smallimage_x32.bmp
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\aartoni\Documents\innosetup\setup_icon.ico
Compression=lzma/normal
SolidCompression=no
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\aartoni\Documents\innosetup\progetti\MRV\bin\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Permissions: everyone-full
Source: "C:\Users\aartoni\Documents\innosetup\progetti\MRV\DB\*"; DestDir: "{app}\DB"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Permissions: everyone-full
Source: "Files\speech.tlb"; DestDir: "{syswow64}"; Flags: ignoreversion  regtypelib
Source: "Files\midas.dll"; DestDir: "{syswow64}"; Flags: ignoreversion regserver
Source: "Files\MSVCR71.dll"; DestDir: "{syswow64}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Files\PrjBridgeMrv.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion regserver
;Source: "Files\Con Firmax64\KpkiCOM_Lock_2.0\KpkiCOM_lock.dll"; DestDir: "{syswow64}"; Flags: ignoreversion 32bit regserver; Components: FIRMA
;Source: "Files\Con Firmax64\KpkiCOM_Lock_2.0\SC_ATR.KPKI"; DestDir: "{syswow64}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: FIRMA

[Dirs]
Name: {app}; Permissions: everyone-full
Name: "{app}\Config"
Name: "{app}\Log"

[Registry]
; Imported Registry File: "C:\Users\aartoni\Documents\innosetup\progetti\MRV\Files\mrv_registry.reg"
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ANDRA\MRV"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ConfigFile"; ValueData: "ConfigFile.ini"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Permissions: everyone-full
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ANDRA\MRV"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "DirDefault"; ValueData: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MRV"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Permissions: everyone-full
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\ANDRA\MRV"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ConfigFile"; ValueData: "ConfigFile.ini"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\ANDRA\MRV"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "DirDefault"; ValueData: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MRV"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "Wow6432Node\CLSID\{{0F6C2140-F48F-4576-90EB-5D5D1BEDC58C}"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "BridgeMRV Object"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "Wow6432Node\CLSID\{{0F6C2140-F48F-4576-90EB-5D5D1BEDC58C}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "AppID"; ValueData: "{{0F6C2140-F48F-4576-90EB-5D5D1BEDC58C}"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "Wow6432Node\AppID\{{0F6C2140-F48F-4576-90EB-5D5D1BEDC58C}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "DllSurrogate"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{{0F6C2140-F48F-4576-90EB-5D5D1BEDC58C}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "DllSurrogate"; Flags: uninsdeletekey

[Types]
Name: "Full"; Description: "Full installation (MRV client + database)"
Name: "Client"; Description: "MRV client installation"

[Components]
Name: "database"; Description: "Server db"; Types:  Full
Name: "dictation"; Description: "Dictation Options"; Types: Client

[Tasks]
Name: "voisis"; Description: "voisis"; Flags: checkablealone; Components: dictation
Name: "recomed"; Description: "recomed"; Flags: checkablealone; Components: dictation

[Code]

var
      Page0: TInputQueryWizardPage;
      Page1: TInputDirWizardPage;


procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
 { Create the pages }

  Page0 := CreateInputQueryPage(wpSelectComponents,'SQL Informations', '','Please specify Server and Instance name , then click Next.');

      Page0.Add('Server:', False);
      Page0.Add('Instance:', False);
      Page0.Add('SQL User:', False);
      Page0.Add('SQL Password:', True);
      Page0.Values[0] := ('localhost');
      Page0.Values[1] := ('WISE');
      Page0.Values[2] := ('sa');
      Page0.Values[3] := ('SectraPACS'); 

      Page1 := CreateInputDirPage(Page0.ID,'Select MRV Database files Location', '','MRV DB data files will be stored in the following folder.'#13#10#13#10 +'To continue, click Next. ' +'If you would like to select a different folder, click Browse.',False, 'New Folder');
      Page1.Add('Database Folder');
      Page1.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{pf}\MRV\DB\');   


end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;

var
      ResultCode: Integer;
      Params: string;
      ScriptPath: string;
      DBPath: string;
      Server: String;
      Instance: String;
      SQL_User: String; 
      SQL_Password: String;

begin

      DBPath := Page1.Values[0];
      Server:= Page0.Values[0];
      Instance:= Page0.Values[1];
      SQL_User:= Page0.Values[2]; 
      SQL_Password:= Page0.Values[3];
      ScriptPath := ExpandConstant('"{app}\DB\install_db_2.30.0.sql"');
      Params := '-v MRVDATA="'+DBPath+'" MRVINDEX="'+DBPath+'" MRVLOG="'+DBPath+'" -S '+Server+'\'+Instance+' -U '+SQL_User+' -P '+SQL_Password+' -i '+ScriptPath+' -o "'+DBPath+'\log.txt"' ;

      if not DirExists(DBPath) then  begin    CreateDir(DBPath);

end;

      if  MsgBox('' + Params + '', mbInformation, mb_YesNo) = idYes then
        if CurPageID = Page1.ID then
begin 
        Exec ('sqlcmd',Params, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
      Exit;
  end;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;

begin

    Result := False;

  if (Page0.ID=PageID) or (Page1.ID=PageID) then

    Result := not IsComponentSelected('database'); 
end;
```

Comment: See [Inno Setup: how to use {app} in InitializeWizard Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4314294/850848).

Comment: i try to replace {app} with "C:\" for test and I realized that the real problem is not the variable but the NextButtonClick code and i don't understand were is wrong.

Comment: So edit your question to ask about your current problem.

Comment: In comments, you've now asked a totally different question than what you've asked here. If you have a new question, use the *Ask Question* button at the top of the page and ask it there. You cannot change this one now because you've already got answers to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to execute your code in `NextButtonClick` only on the "Select Destination Location" page. For that you need to test the value of `CurPageID` argument:

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
{ ... }
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    { Your code }
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: i need to execute my code in NextButtonClick on Page1

Comment: I do not know what Page 1 is.

Comment: after procedure InitializeWizard i create 2 pages. page0=CreateInputQueryPage and Page1=CreateInputDirPage. i need to run my code into Page1. i suppose the page id of page1 is Page1. it's wrong?

Comment: OK, so now you have a question to ask: *"Handling Next button click on a custom page"*.

Answer (score 0):

`NextButtonClick` is called for all pages.  You must test the `CurPageID` parameter to limit processing for a specific page.

In this case, since you appear to be capturing values related to both of your custom pages, you probably should delay processing at least until after `Page1` -- so you should check if `CurPageID = Page1.ID`, as is already demonstrated in other parts of your code.

There is another alternative -- you can declare a page-specific `NextButtonClick` handler instead of a global one.  You can see an example of that at [this page](https://www.mirality.co.nz/inno/isd.php).

---

Having said all of that, if the thing you're trying to do actually makes changes to the user's system (as seems likely), then doing it at `NextButtonClick` during the wizard is entirely the wrong thing to do in the first place.

The wizard should only be used to gather and validate installation parameters.  You should not actually start installing anything until the user has agreed to actually start the install by clicking the Install button.

In this case, you should put the code into the `PrepareToInstall` function instead.  Or if it requires some `[Files]` to be installed beforehand, then you should put it into `CurStepChanged`, conditioned on `CurStep = ssPostInstall`.